# JSP меняет поле с объектом на null (Spring MVC)

Tags: spring, jsp

Есть класс `Task` который связан как `ManyToOne` с классом `Person`. Если я отправляю объект `Task` со всеми инициализированными полями в `jsp` на `GET` запрос, то потом через `POST` получаю этот же класс, но с `null` во всех полях, которые до этого содержали ссылки на `Person`. Ниже присутствует код обоих классов и страницы `jsp`. Пробовал делать `Person` `serializable`, пробовал добавить поле `@Transient Person executor` вообще без зависимости. В любом случае в методе `public String updateTask(@ModelAttribute("task") Task task)` `task` приезжает с `null` `client` и `executor`.

Конечно можно после получения объекта заново вытягивать эти поля из БД, но хотелось бы сделать все элегантнее

класс `Task`

```
@Entity
@AccessType(Type.PROPERTY)
@NamedQueries(value = { 
    @NamedQuery(
            name=Task.GET_BY_CLIENT, 
            query="select t from Task t "+
                        "where t.client = :client"),
    @NamedQuery(
            name=Task.GET, 
            query="select t from Task t "+
                        "left join fetch t.client " +
                        "where t.id = :id")
})
public class Task {
public static final String GET_BY_CLIENT = "Task.getByClient";
public static final String GET = "Task.get";


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column
private String name = "";
@Column
private String description = "";

@Column
private Date creationTime;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private Person client;

@Transient
private Person executor;

//getters, setters and other logic
```

и класс `Person`

```
@Entity
@AccessType(Type.PROPERTY)
@NamedQueries(value = { 
    @NamedQuery(
            name=Person.GET, 
            query="select distinct p from Person p "+
                        "left join fetch p.tasks " +
                        "where p.id = :id")
})
public class Person implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1631816823945986338L;

public static final String GET = "Person.get";

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column
private String name = "";

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval=true)
private List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

//getters, setters, etc
```

К этому делу есть контроллер `TaskController`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addTask", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView addTask() {
    ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("task");
    view.addObject("task", new Task());
    return view;
}

@RequestMapping(value = {"/addTask", "/editTask"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateTask(@ModelAttribute("task") Task task) {
    taskService.save(task);
    return "redirect:/";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/editTask", method =RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView editTask(@RequestParam(value="id", defaultValue="0") Long id) {
    Task task = taskService.find(id);
    task.setExecutor(new Person());
    ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("task");
    view.addObject("task", task);
    return view;
}
```

Все это дело отображается через jsp

```
<form:form commandName="task" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <h3><span class="label label-default">${task.id > '0' ? "Edit ": "Add "} task</span></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <c:if test="${task.client != null}">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="document.location='editPerson?id=${task.client.id}'">${task.client.name}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </c:if>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <form:input path="name" class="form-control" id="name"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <form:textarea path="description" class="form-control" id="description" rows="10"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Смените

   ```
   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   ```

   на

   ```
   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
   ```
2. Вызовите `task.getPerson()`
3. Или настройте Hibernate-сессию, так что бы она не умирала до рендеринга JSP.

Судя по указанным симптомам, ситуация такова, вы получаете `class Task` но свойство `private Person client` остается не заполненным, т.к. выставленно `@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)`, что означает, что данные будут подтянуты при обращении. Далее объект возвращается из метода, и вовремя рендеринга Hibernate-сессии уже нет. ==> Дозаполнить незаполненные поля уже не получиться.